# How to give range in countifs using cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Iam wondering if someone can help me with this Excel formula about **COUNTIFS** , instead of giving range using numbers ie.

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A200,">200",A2:A200,"<=900")
```

Can we use cells for range reference ie.

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A200,">C7",A2:A200,"<=C8")
```

I've actually tried this but getting **0** as output.
Can someone help me with this.

Comment: `COUNTIFS(A2:A200,">"&C7,A2:A200,"<="&C8)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A200,">"&C7,A2:A200,"<="&C8)
```

Comment: Again, explaining _why_ this is the answer would be useful.  Code only answers are generally regarded as low quality and may attract downvotes or be deleted.   Also, copying a comment verbatim is bad form.  Attribution is required

Comment: @chrisneilsen sir, truly said, I found you have posted the solution way before, it was posted in the answers, at least a credit should be provided. Even if he has created then some explanations.